# How to define a large prime number (for example, $7919$)?

Tags: prime-numbers, definition, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

The set of natural numbers may be defined using Peano Axioms:

[image]

Under this definition of natural numbers, one may define $1$ as $0^+$, $2$ as $(0^+)^+$, $7$ as $((((((0^+)^+)^+)^+)^+)^+)^+$, etc.

My question is, how does one define a large prime number such as $7919$? Surely one may define it by literally writing $0$ followed by $7919$ copies of $+$'s (how practical is this writing?), or simplify defining $$7919= (((0^+)^+)\cdots)^+$$ specifying that there are $7919$ plus symbols. But this would be a circular definition as we are trying to define $7919$ without using the number $7919$.

Since $7919$ is a prime, I failed to see anyway of defining it using multiplication as well.

How does one define the number $7919$ using precise and concise language?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Is it possible you are mixing up the words "definition" with "notation"? The Peano axioms you quote provide a definition for all natural numbers (including large prime numbers). The notation you suggest is, indeed, the result you would get from iterating 7919 times. But, there is no need to use that notation when you can just as easily write $7919$.

Answer (score 4):

If you have addition and multiplication we can write

$$7919=7\cdot 10^3+9\cdot 10^2+1\cdot 10^1+9.$$

All the digits can easily be defined by your plus notation and $10^n$ can be defined recursively as $10\cdot 10^{n-1}$.

Comment: So you need a (recursive) definition of exponentiation as well ....

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no problem with defining it as 
$$7919=(((0^+)^+)\dots)^+.$$
Your objection seems to be writing, for example, that there are "$7919$ $+$ signs". But we don't need to do so, we can always in theory write out the finitely many plus signs to define the number. There's absolutely nothing circular here, and writing "$7919$ $+$ signs" is merely a matter of notation and does not lead to conceptual circularity.